# ObjectOutput/InputStream socket file transfer pause feature

Tags: java, swing, sockets, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I'm working on a Graduation project in which we have to Transfer files client-server, implementing pause/resume function.

I'm used to using Object out/input streams to make communications, but I don't see how I could implement the Pausing feature. Any ideas on how to approach this problem?

I know about writing byte to byte on the Output stream, but I didn't want to reinvent the wheel.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Impossible to say without further information. For example, if you're transferring an entire file as a single object, you can't pause that.

Comment: It is also unclear what you mean by "pausing", and also what transport you are using. Are you talking about disconnecting the connection and later making a new connection and resuming where you left off? Or are you talking about merely not sending data on the connection for a while and then resuming the data transfer on the same connection? The latter is much simpler - you can make a `PausableOutputStream` that will just block on anyone calling `write` until it is resumed.